# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function at LoadBooks

Tags: javascript

i am trying to get the data in the json file  from an api , and this the code i used but it is not working

```
  async  function LoadBooks() {
        const response= await fetch(api_url);
        const data= await response; 
        data.forEach(book=>{
            console.log(docs.title_suggest);
            console.log(docs.seed);

        });
```

Comment: I suppose you need to use `const data = await response.json()`, as fetch returns a `Response` object and you need to parse it further.

Comment: Well your code assumes that `data` is an array, but apparently it is not.

Comment: Also once you fixed that,  not sure you want `docs.title_suggest`, but maybe `book.title_suggest`, as docs doesn't appear anywhere..

Answer (score 1):

`response` here is already awaited, and so you need to call `.json()` or `.text()` to convert it

```js
  async  function LoadBooks() {
        const response= await fetch(api_url);
        const data= await response.json(); // parsing the result
        data.forEach(book=>{
            console.log(docs.title_suggest);
            console.log(docs.seed);

        });
```